# View changes to Selmer templates without restarting server

Tags: clojure, jetty, selmer

I'm creating a web app with Clojure using [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer) templates. I'm using Jetty, and I have to restart it to see my changes. I want to see my changes without restarting the server. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to migrate to [http-kit](http://www.http-kit.org/migration.html) to get hot code reload, it's very easy

Add `[http-kit "2.1.18"]` to your `project.clj` and `org.httpkit.server` to your `use` block, and  just replace `run-jetty` with `run-server`. See details in the link above

Comment: Thank you but i've solved this problem. There is solution on project file. I just added this part like '
{:ring
    {:open-browser? false, :stacktraces? false, :auto-reload? true}}
'.